# How do I show a message after the right answer in the array has been chosen?

Tags: swift

So this is the program I use an array for my questions and answers. The first answer in the array is always right, but it randomises in the actual app.

I want to find out how to do something like, if someone gets the answer right, the screen fades to a different colour and tells them if they're right or not, and say for example "Yes Germany have won the most derbies" shows it on screen for a few seconds and the game carries on.

Sorry if that's a bit too much, but if you can help I'd really appreciate it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ARRAY THAT CONTAINS QUESTIONS
    let questions = ["Who's won the most England-Germany derbies in the world cup?", "Which match has had the most cards in the world cup?", "Who has done the best in the world cup"]

    // ARRAY THAT CONTAINS ANSWERS
    let answers = [["Germany", "England"], ["Portugal vs Netherlands", "England vs Spain"], ["Lionel Messi", "Christiano Ronaldo"]]

    //Variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
    var points = 0;

    //Label
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel?

    // start button
    @IBOutlet weak var start: UIButton? ///////////////////////////////////////

    //Button
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject){
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)){
            print ("RIGHT!")
            points += 1
        } else {
            print ("WRONG!!!!!!")
        }

        if (currentQuestion != questions.count) {
            newQuestion()
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScore", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        newQuestion()
    }

    //Function that displays new question
    func newQuestion() {
        lbl?.text = questions[currentQuestion]

        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(2)+1

        //Create a button
        var button:UIButton? = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...2 {
            //Create a button
            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton!

            if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)) {
                button?.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
            } else {
                button?.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                x = 1
            }
        }
        currentQuestion += 1
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        start?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do what you're doing but I hope this sort of helps and gives you a few pointers. All the best and merry chirstmas!

```
let questions = ["Who's won the most England-Germany derbies in the world cup?", "Which match has had the most cards in the world cup?", "Who has done the best in the world cup"]

let answers = [["Germany", "England"], ["Portugal vs Netherlands", "England vs Spain"], ["Lionel Messi", "Christiano Ronaldo"]]

var questionNumber: Int = 0 // first question
var correctAnswer: Int = 0 // choose correct answer
var points: Int = 0

func handleAnswerChosen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 { // make sure that your number tags are always 0 and 1. 0 for the first answer, 1 for the second.
        if questionNumber == 0 && sender.tag == correctAnswer {
            print("CORRECT")

// MARK: SHOW CORRECT ANSWER AND SELECTED ANSWER.

            print(answers[questionNumber][correctAnswer]) // CORRECT ANSWER
            print(answers[questionNumber][sender.tag]) // ANSWER SELECTED

            handleNextQuestion()
        }
    }
}

func handleNextQuestion() {
    questionNumber += 1 // Do this as well as update to the next question.

    if questionNumber == 0 { // first question
        correctAnswer = 1 // second answer
    } else if questionNumber == 1 {
        correctAnswer = 0 // first answer
    }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScore", sender: self) 
}

// The first [0] gets the two possible answers. The second [1] gets the second answer of the two possible answers chosen.
print(answers[0][1]) // this prints England which is the first question and the second answer of the first question
```

Comment: Thanks a-lot :) It helped

Comment: Is there a way to print the answer for each question? It always prints the answer "England" for each of my questions

Comment: After updating to the next question by calling handleNextQuestion, you can still call print(answers) but instead of using [0][1], you can use print(answers[questionNumber][correctAnswer]). I'll update my answer to help.

Comment: Do you know why my buttons are now unresponsive?

Comment: @mak if you're using storyboards, you want to drag your button as an outlet (not an action) into your code so you are able to use it via code. After this, you're then able to add the handleAnswerChosen function to the target of that button so when tapped, it calls that function like so:

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleAnswerChosen(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: @mak You want to do that for all the buttons. Make sure you set your button tags like: button.tag = 0, button.tag = 1